# ggplot + scale_x_reverse with limits is throwing away all of the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some data with ggplot2 but I find that if I combine the scale_x_reverse function while defining limits all of the data get excluded as missing.

For instance, in the test data set at the bottom of this post, I want to plot "Depth", on the y axis against "corvals" on the x-axis. I also want the y axis to have 0 at the top, and the deepest depth on the bottom, as well as to only show the top 150m.

I think reasonable code to accomplish this would look like

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(Depth, corvals)) + 
geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse(limits = c(0, 150))
```

however in that case I get the warning message

> Warning message:

```
Removed 19 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

and then the plot doesn't show any data points.

In contrast the following two code samples do work.

Limits, but doesn't flip depth axis:

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(Depth, corvals)) + 
geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + xlim(0, 150)
```

Flips, but doesn't limit depth axis:

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(Depth, corvals)) + 
geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse()
```

Is there some way to use these two features together that I am missing?

> testdata

```
Depth   corvals

10    0.0000
48 1047.6866
52  919.3938
55  304.5824
58  297.3390
63    0.0000
80    0.0000
85    0.0000
90    0.0000
95    0.0000
100    0.0000
110    0.0000
125    0.0000
140    0.0000
150    0.0000
170    0.0000
180    0.0000
200    0.0000
500    0.0000
```

Comment: Flip the order of the `limits` argument in `scale_x_reverse`. `ggplot(testdata, aes(Depth, corvals)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse(limits = c(150, 0))`

Answer (score 2):

Chrisss's answer in the comments worked well. I just had to flip the order of the limits so the larger number goes first.

```
  ggplot(testdata, aes(Depth, corvals)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse(limits = c(150, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

if I run the following script with your data - not all the null-values as you have(it would have been great, if some useable data were delivered) - it works. The diagram is plotted as expected.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(10,48,52,55,58, 63, 80, 85, 100, 150, 300, 500)
y <- c(0,1047.6866, 919.3938, 304.5824, 297.339,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p <- p +coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse()
p
p + xlim(150,0)
```

There is warning showing up that - in this case - two values were removed. These are the two values which were cut off by the xlim(150,0).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to subset the data beforehand, since you don't want to show the data beyond Depth 150:

```
ggplot(subset(testdata, Depth <= 150), aes(Depth, corvals)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse()
```